# Tell UserManager to use AspNetRoles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to migrate a MVC3 Application to MVC5. I have Used these Articles:

- http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682113/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Role

The old Application use the Database First Model (modeled with the EDMX file).

When I try to update the Role of a User I got following Error:

> Additional information: The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context.

In this Method (um.AddToRole):

```
public bool AddUserToRole(string userId, string roleName)
    {
        var um = new UserManager<AspNetUsers>(
            new UserStore<AspNetUsers>(new Entities()));
        var idResult = um.AddToRole(userId, roleName);
        return idResult.Succeeded;
    }
```

How Can I tell the UserManager to Use the AspNetRoles Class?

Best Regards,
Marko

AspNetUsers

```
namespace NursingHome.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AspNetUsers
    {
        public AspNetUsers()
        {
            this.AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaims>();
            this.AspNetUserLogins = new HashSet<AspNetUserLogins>();
            this.NursingHome = new HashSet<NursingHome>();
            this.AspNetRoles = new HashSet<AspNetRoles>();
        }

        //public string Id { get; set; }
        //public string UserName { get; set; }
        //public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        //public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        public string Discriminator { get; set; }
        public System.Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string LegacyPasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
        public string MobileAlias { get; set; }
        public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
        public string MobilePIN { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string LoweredEmail { get; set; }
        public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }
        public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
        public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastLockoutDate { get; set; }
        public int FailedPasswordAttemptCount { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart { get; set; }
        public int FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<NursingHome> NursingHome { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AspNetUsers Extension

```
public partial class AspNetUsers : IdentityUser
{
}
```

AspNetRoles

```
public partial class AspNetRoles
{
    public AspNetRoles()
    {
        this.AspNetUsers = new HashSet<AspNetUsers>();
    }

    //public string Id { get; set; }
    //public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}
```

AspNetRoles Extension

```
public partial class AspNetRoles : IdentityRole
{
    public AspNetRoles(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }
}
```

DB Context Extension

```
public partial class Entities : IdentityDbContext<AspNetUsers>
{
    public Entities()
        : base("NursingHomesEntities")
    {
    }
}
```

## Update

Installed Packages

- Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
- Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
- Install-Package EntityFramework
- Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
- Install-Package Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC
- Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre
- Install-Package FontAwesome

Next Steps

- EDMX File added (from database created)
- Added one table with reference to AspNetUser.

Now I get following error:

```
Model compatibility cannot be checked because the DbContext instance was not created using Code First patterns. DbContext instances created from an ObjectContext or using an EDMX file cannot be checked for compatibility.
```

***Is it not possible to use edmx file and mvc5 together?***

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend to use, a new asp.net identity 2.0 beta: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-beta1

It is better and more flexible to override and use. You can get some information, samples and other things here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/11/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-beta1.aspx

I can't reproduce this error, but probably is in the mapping configuration, a entity framework error and not a asp.net MVC error.. 
You need to take some care, replace all uses of dbcontext in your app, there is a topic to take a look to avoid this error: [The entity type <type> is not part of the model for the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688922/the-entity-type-type-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context)

If is still not working, try make some tests and experiences or add more information here.