# Entity Framework dynamic model not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model, sqlanywhere, dbset

I'm starting working with the Entity Framework 6 and got a problem with dynamic models. I have the following model:

```
public class EF6
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public int Int2 { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }
    public byte[] Doc { get; set; }
}
```

Which is added to the context like this:

```
Entities ent = new Entities();
var dbSet = ent.Set<EF6>();

EF6 e = new EF6();
e.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
e.Int2 = 123;
e.Str = "Hello World";
e.Doc = new byte[1] { 0 };

dbSet.Add(e);
```

But on the `dbSet.Add(e)` part, i get the following error: `The entity type EF6 is not part of the model for the current context.`

Does any one has an solution for this problem?

**EDIT**

Later i want to write some of my models in IronPython and add them over `dbSet.Add`.

**EDIT 2**

[image]

Comment: seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688922/the-entity-type-type-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context

Comment: @user1666620 i don't want to use code first, my table already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
 testEntities entityt = new testEntities();
        var dbset = entityt.Set<TestTable>();

        TestTable TT = new TestTable();
        TT.City = "AHD";
        TT.Name = "Ajay";
        TT.Nr = "1236578";
        dbset.Add(TT);

        entityt.SaveChanges();
```

This is working for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in my case (look at the picture) it did not work.

Comment: Are you sure that the class EF6 is part of your edmx ?

Check again. because I have tried to replicate this error and I am successful to get this error. My class is not part of edmx and I got this error.

Comment: No, it is not part of the edmx, because i've added the model "dynamically". Can i add a model dynamically to the edmx?

Comment: then you have to go for Code first approach.

Comment: I don't get you what you exactly want. if you have table in DB then why do you need to create dynamically ? You have to Map your model to edmx for successful operation

Comment: For example, i have one DB context, and my models are seperated in different assemblies. So i have an existing database with all tables in it. But not all tables are loaded into the designer. (edmx).