# MVC 4 connection string can't login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making a website using MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5.0.And I'm suposed to have a page where the user can be capable to see his data(name,email,age etc...).Problem is when trying to acess that database, the program breaks and it returns

> ```
> " An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code "
> ```

And in the inner exception it gives this error :

> ```
>  `{"Cannot open database \"BookMania.Models.PerfilContext\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'TAG000002717\\teste'."}`
> ```

I think It may happen because I'm defining my connection string in the Web.Config wrongly.

```
`add name="PerfilContexto" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModeloBookmania.csdl|res://*/ModeloBookmania.ssdl|res://*/ModeloBookmania.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=C:\Users\teste.TAG000002717\Documents\BD.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`
```

Being "PerfilContexto" the model in wich i call the class Dbcontext

```
public class PerfilContext :DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Perfil>  Dados { get; set; } 
}
```

Any Ideas? :o

UPDATED : The Connection String is already Solved, Many Thanks to the user Pawel Maga.

Still that exception still exists.

Altough, now gives an An adittional information :  The entity type Perfil is not part of the model for the current context.

Here's the controller part where gives the error:

```
    public ActionResult Perfil(int userid=1)

        if(Session["UserID"] == null)

            return View(); // if there's no session, it runs blank,cause in the view there's a code to redirect to homepage if there's no session.


       var ida=Session["UserID"]; //After login this variable keeps the user id
       userid = Convert.ToInt32(ida);//the varaible is converted to int
        PerfilContext contexto = new PerfilContext();
     /* gives error about "Perfil" wich is the model for the view*/ 
         Perfil conteXto = contexto.Dados.Single(perf=>perf.ID == userid);
        return View(conteXto);
    `
```

Comment: Oh, and  the db is using Windows  Authentication has login method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set a incorrect name for connection string.

Your dbcontext class name: *PerfilContext*

Your connectionstring name: *PerfilContexto*

Change connectionstring name to **PerfilContext** or explicity pass this name to base constructor:

```
 public class PerfilContext : DbContext
 { 
      public PerfilContext()
         :base("PerfilContexto")
      {
      }

      public DbSet<Perfil>  Dados { get; set; } 
 }
```

Comment: '-' Omg, thanks bro.
Im still a newbie in this things x)
Still, it doesn't run.

on the controller it gives that exception error,and gives an adittional information.
         
"Additional information: The entity type Perfil is not part of the model for the current context."

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688922/the-entity-type-type-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context

Comment: Thanks again bro ;). I'l give it a try.I'm just downloading the newest version of Sql Management, to create a DB on a local server.

Comment: Many thanks bro. I've been all day trying to figure out what was wrong and you solved it in less than 10 minutes.Many thanks bro ;)