# Make generic Type on function as Generic Object

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a function which make repository Dictionary, of multiple tables at run time, What i want is make this as generic, but I am stuck on this error..

```
 public IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>(string TypeName) where TEntity : class 

 {

        Type t = GetInstance(TypeName);
        if (_repositories.Keys.Contains(t))
        {
            return _repositories[t] as IRepository<TEntity>;
        }

        var repository = new Repository<TEntity>(_context);

        _repositories.Add(t, repository);

        return repository;
 }
```

When I call this function as

```
 string tn = tt.GetType().FullName;
 Type tttt = GetInstance(tn);
 uu.GetRepository<Object>(tn).Add(tt);
```

it throws `Exception`

> The entity type Object is not part of the model for the current context.

how can I make this happen as

```
string tn = tt.GetType().FullName;
Type tttt = GetInstance(tn);
uu.GetRepository<typeof(tt)>(tn).Add(tt);
```

or something type else.

Comment: You can make it via reflection, but what's the point? It will then ignore all benefits of generic type parameters. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Do you initialize function "uu" ?

Comment: you are using Entity Framework?

Comment: @Evk i have a scenerio through which every time I wanted to save and update, delete all records dynamically which were created dynamically.

Comment: @LinhTuan, yeah I initialize uu

Comment: @SurenSrapyan, yeah this logic is implement in Entity framework

Comment: @user6002727 See this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688922/the-entity-type-type-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know how to do it in principle (if ignore questions about should you do that at all or not), then here is how:

```
 string tn = tt.GetType().FullName;
 // get reference to GetRepository<TEntity>
 var genericGet = uu.GetType().GetMethod("GetRepository").MakeGenericMethod(tt.GetType());
 // invoke to get IRepository<TEntity>
 var repository = genericGet.Invoke(uu, new object[] { tn});
 // get IRepository<TEntity>.Add
 var addMethod = repository.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
 // invoke
 addMethod.Invoke(repository, new object[] { tt});
```

If you would go this way - better make your `Add` methods accept object instead of generic type argument, and so make your interface just `IRepository`, not `IRepository<T>`. Then inside repository - get reference to specific `DbSet` and `Add` method using technique above.

Comment: Yeah, It's Work, but If there any solution other than this?

Comment: @user6002727 as I remember, Entity Framework context has untyped DbSets. Something like context.Set(typeof(YourEntity)). You can just use those sets then (again, your IRepository would be without generic parameters).

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be generic, you need to specify a type as a generic parameter.
The client code must know the type, not just have an instance of that type.

In your case, using `Object` as a generic type argument does not make sense, because that would not provide the type inference for the underlying framework. That is the reason for the exception thrown.

Also, at runtime, if your solution is multithreaded, you can't use Dictionary without extra synchronization. For your task, I'd recommend ConcurrentDictionary.

```
void Main()
{
    var repository = GetRepository<MyEntity1>();
    MyEntity1 instance = repository.Get(1);
}

class MyEntity1
{
}

ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> repositories = new ConcurrentDictionary<System.Type, object>();

interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Get(int id);
}

class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T:new()
{
    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T:new()
{
    return (IRepository<T>)repositories.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), t => new Repository<T>());
}
```

Comment: Nice Idea of `ConcurrentDictionary`.. like that