# RoleManager.Roles throw an exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

Whereever I try to access the Roles property of RoleManager, it raise an exception in ASP.NET Identity,
        Role is not part of the model for the current context

```
Could you please assist me in that.
```

Thanks
Imran

Comment: Show your `RoleManager` instantiation

Comment: app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688922/the-entity-type-type-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context