# How can I write generic query in asp .net mvc for 3 different tables in db context with LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics, dynamic

I have 3 different tables and 3 different columns which are primary columns.

```
 public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teacher
    {
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lesson
    {
        public int LessonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


var _context = new MyContext()

_context.Student(x=>x.StudentId == someValue)
```

or

```
_context.Teacher(x=>x.TeacherId == someValue)
```

or

```
_context.Lesson(x=>x.TeacherId == someValue)
```

only changing table name and key value.

What is the best way using generic method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a general repository and than inherit it with native repository of each class like this

```
public class GeneralRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private MyContext Context = new MyContext();
        protected DbSet<T> Dbset { get; set; }
        public GeneralRepository()
        {
           Dbset = Context.Set<T>();
        }

    public T SelectByID(int? id)
    {
        var Record = Dbset.Find(id);
        return (Record);
    }

  public class StudentRepositoy :GeneralRepository<Student>
    {



    }
```

Make a object of native repositry and call the function

Where ever you need to call the function make a object of student repository

```
StudentRepositoy repository = new StudentRepositoy();
var result = repository.SelectByID(3);
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried. but i says The entity type Student is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: @MaldioRobert check it , I explained briefly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688922/the-entity-type-type-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use a pattern like "generic repository". Or you can simply write a method takes Expression> as input and pass the expression to it.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/generic-repository-pattern-ddea2262

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814768/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Generic-Repository-Patte