# Entity Framework - Entity type X is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm working with the Entity Framework to provide access to a datastore - however, I'm running into an error that I don't quite understand.

Specifically, 'The entity type AnomalyQuery is not part of the model for the current context.'

This error occurs at

```
    using (PHSRP_DashboardDBEntities _DBC = new PHSRP_DashboardDBEntities())
    {
        //to be replaced by proper table -- anomaly query
        var ListAnomalies = _DBC.AnomalyQueries
                                .OrderBy(p => p.QueryName)
                                .ToList();

        lbx_PickAnomalies.DataSource = ListAnomalies;
    }
```

PHSRP_DashboardDBEntities (which extends DbContext), has the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AnomalyQuery>().ToTable("AnomalyQuery");
    modelBuilder.Entity<AnomalyParameter>().ToTable("AnomalyParameter");

    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
}
```

I implemented this due to an answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688922/the-entity-type-type-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context), however I'm not sure it's relevant as it's never referenced.

Additionally, the following DbSets are instantiated within PHSRP_DashboardDBEntities:

```
public virtual DbSet<AnomalyParameter> AnomalyParameters { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<AnomalyQuery> AnomalyQueries { get; set; }
```

These two classes (AnomalyParameter and AnomalyQuery) are defined within the DataModel for PHSRP_DashboardDBEntities, thus should be valid classes.

E.g.

```
public partial class AnomalyQuery
{
    public AnomalyQuery()
    {
        this.AnomalyParameters = new ObservableListSource<AnomalyParameter>();
    }

    public int QueryID { get; set; }
    public string QueryName { get; set; }
    public string QueryText { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ObservableListSource<AnomalyParameter> AnomalyParameters { get; set; }
}
```

Is defined within PHSRP_DashboardDataModel.tt

Thus, to me, it seems that the entity type AnomalyQuery is certainly part of the model for the current context, and, as a result, I'm not sure how to resolve this error.

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception in `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: The intention of this exception is to force the database mapping to be handled by the framework itself. To be sure - I commented out this line and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Which would cause your `.ToTable` mappings to be ignored. Try removing that exception. I haven't used database-first or model-first in ages. If that solves the problem, look at your .tt file to understand how to accomplish the same thing from a model-first perspective.

Comment: I must've edited my comment right as you were posting that -- so I commented that out and the same error occurred.

Comment: Wow.. the corresponding table for AnomalyParameters in the database was misspelled as AmomalyParameters .. correcting for this fixed the bug.