# The entity type <AdminLogin> is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am not sure why this error is coming. Below My code:

**Context:**

```
public partial class AdminLoginEntities : DbContext
    {
        public AdminLoginEntities() : base("name=AdminLoginEntities"){ }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            modelBuilder.Entity<AdminLogin>().ToTable("AdminLogin");
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<AdminLogin> AdminLogins { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Code:

```
AdminLoginEntities objadminE = new AdminLoginEntities();
      [HttpPost]
            [Route("AddAdmin")]
            public IHttpActionResult InserNewAdmin(AdminLogin data)
            {
                if(!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
                try
                {
                    objadminE.AdminLogins.Add(data);
                    objadminE.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                return Ok(data);
            }
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Check the connection string. See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/24178136/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24178136/6630084). Perhaps this is your case.

Comment: @Jackdaw checked not working

Comment: CTRL+Click over AdminLogin in both Controller and dbContext. Check both point to same class and verify class Namespaces